# Error en Flex y Yacc (warning: "YYSTYPE" redefined) (warning: assignment to ‘int’ from ‘char *’)

Tags: c++, c, compilador, flex, yacc

Buen dia,tengo una consulta con este codigo, estoy tratando de hacer un pequeño compilador de java con flex y yacc, al hacer el make, me da los siguientes mensajes de error:
[Log de error](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rK7rDMTCqKtqorcFhFVPJIBzO7wwrDJf/view?usp=share_link)

Aqui un fragmento de mi codigo:

```
%{
    #include <string.h>
    #include "y.tab.h"

    #define YYSTYPE char*

    int line = 1;
%}

letter                      [a-zA-Z]
digit                       [0-9]

%%

[ \t\r]+                                            {   /* skip */    }
"."{letter}({letter}|{digit}|"_")*  { yylval = strdup(yytext); return _POINT_ID;}
{letter}({letter}|{digit}|"_")*"[" { yylval = strdup(yytext); return _ARRAY_VALUE;}

"eol"                       { yylval = strdup(yytext);  return _CHAR;     }
"switch"                    { yylval = strdup(yytext); return _SWITCH; }
"void"                      {yylval = strdup(yytext);  return _VOJD;}
"while"                     { yylval = strdup(yytext); return _WHILE; }
"break"                     { yylval = strdup(yytext); return _BREAK; }
"null"                       { yylval = strdup(yytext);  return _NULL;     }
"print"                    { yylval = strdup(yytext); return _PRINTF; }
"program"                   { yylval = strdup(yytext); return _PROGRAM;}
"class"                     { yylval = strdup(yytext); return _CLASS; }
"const"                     { yylval = strdup(yytext); return _CONST; }
```

Segun investigue el problema podria estar en la declaracion de #define YYSTYPE char* , pero no comprendo como deberia de resolverlo o si es algo mas.  Me podrian ayudar a indicarme que estoy haciendo mal segun el lo de errores, y que deberia de cambiarle al codigo.

Comment: Bienvenido. Pon el log aquí por favor. Si no entra pon una parte y deja el enlace para verlo completo.

Comment: Este seria el log:

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rK7rDMTCqKtqorcFhFVPJIBzO7wwrDJf/view

Comment: Disculpa. Quise decir en la pregunta. Luego borro mis comentarios. Y sería bueno que tu hagas lo mismo. Es solo para que la pregunta sea mejor recibida.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`YYSTYPE` es el tipo del valor semántico --es decir, `yylval`-- lo cual se comparte entre el analizador léxico, generado por lex, y el analizador sintáctico generado por yacc. Por eso, ambos analizadores tienen que tener la misma definición de `YYSTYPE`. Sin embargo, son dos componentes independientes, producido por dos herramientas distintas y guardados en archivos distintos. Entonces, la concordancia entre las definiciones de `YYSTYPE` no es automático.

Por defecto, YYSTYPE es una macro definida en y.tab.h. Si no tiene otra definición, se definirá como `int`. Si buscas en `y.tab.h`, encontrarías algo como

```c
#ifndef YYSTYPE
#define YYSTYPE int
#endif
```

La idea es que se puede cambiar la definición por otro tipo, y si lo haces, `YYSTYPE` sería definida y la condición `#ifndef YYSTYPE` (es decir, "si `YYSTYPE` no está definida") va a inhibir la definición como `int`.

Para que esta convención funcione, tienes que poner el `#define YYSTYPE char*` ***antes*** de `#include "y.tab.h"`. Y, por supuesto, también tienes que poner `#define YYSTYPE char*` en el archivo `.y`. Como lo pusiste después, recibes un error de compilación.

De hecho, hoy en día es mucho más probable que estás usando flex y bison, respectivamente, aunque ambos programas tiene modo de compatibilidad con las viejas herramientas. Bison te da una solución mucha mejor, así que vale la pena aprenderlo.

Con Bison, podrías simplemente declarar el tipo semántico utilizando

```
%define api.value.type { char* }
```

Con esto, `YYSTYPE` estará definido en `y.tab.h` como `char*` en lugar de `int`. Con esta definición encrustado en `y.tab.h`, el analizador léxico no tiene que hacer absolutamente nada para obtener la definición correcta. Entonces, si pones el directivo `%define` en tu archivo `.y`, podrías borrar el `#define YYSTYPE` del archivo `.l`, y los dos componentes serán permanentemente sincronizados.

En la práctica, no es tan común que todos los símbolos en la gramática comparten un solo tipo. Normalmente, hay varios tipos y estos se recopilan en una declaración `%unión` que enumera las alternativas. Seguramente, vas a encontrar esta opción más tarde, por lo cual no voy a escribir más; solo quise apuntar que la declaración `%union`, igual que la `#define api.value.type`, cambia la definición de `YYSTYPE` en `y.tab.h`, así que no tienes que repetir la definición en tu archivo `.l`.

Comment: Lo cambie de lugar, y efectivamente me dejo de dar error en el scanner.l , no se si viste el log de error que comparti? alli me aparecen errores en el parser.y  de warning: implicit declaration of function ‘check_type_existance’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration] y en la tabla de simbolos simtab.c warning: return type defaults to ‘int’ [-Wimplicit-int] , se debera tambien al mismo problema de la definicion de yystype??

Comment: @Henry: Si quieres que miramos algo, hay que ponerlo como texto en tu pregunta. Imágenes y servicios de archivos son fatales por alguien que usa un Android y peor por quienes utilizan lectores de pantalla. Pero dudo que los errors en tu comento son relacionado con `YYSTYPE`. Me parece más probable que son  sencillos errores de tecleado. Quizás `check_type_existance` debe ser `check_type_existence`, por ejemplo. En `simtab.c`, tienes una función a cuya definición le falta el tipo de devolución.

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda, efectivamente revise el archivo simtab.c y habian unas funciones que no tendian tipo de devolucion. Gracias.